# Replace Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu Keeping Data in Different Partition

Tags: partitioning

I have already searched to replace Windows with Ubuntu, I got it. The question I have right now in my mind is, is it possible to keep data in different partition and install ubuntu in windows partition.

Suppose,

I have 3 partitions of 500GB HDD,

C - Windows Installed, D - Local Data, E - Local Data,

I want to keep the data of D & E drive as it is, and want to install ubuntu in C without any error.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to install dual boot option with Win8.1 and Ubuntu? Yes that is possible. [http://askubuntu.com/questions/399441/installing-ubuntu-13-10-alongside-windows-8-1] for dualboot

Comment: I only need Ubuntu. So is it possible then ?

Comment: Oh yes got it.  Yes it is possible. You can leave D & E as it is and make sure you do not format it and install the OS alone in one partition :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.
During the installation select the `C:\` drive for th einstallation, the other two partitions will be left allone.

Comment: Ok If they will be left alone, Will they be working fine ?

Comment: Yes you can mount and use them, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is possible. I believe you'll have to select manual partitioning during the installation.

All your three partitions will most likely show up as 'NTFS' partitions, but they won't have their drive letters from Windows. You can however see their disk labels.
During the manual partitioning, for your 'root' partition (mount point in /) select the partition which matches the label of your C drive (if it does not have a label, the one that maches the size).

If you'd like to access the data partitions from Ubuntu too, you will have to select a mount point for those. This can be anything you desire, but make sure that the 'format' checkbox isn't marked.