# How to install Ubuntu on 'C' partition without affecting D?

Tags: windows, partitioning

Sorry to look stupid but it's my first time to install ubuntu or any linux distro actually. I got my HDD with C & D partitions. The 'D' partition has so much important files while 'C' is for windows. I wanna install ubuntu on the 'C' partition without affecting the D partition. Can anyone explain in steps! Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Linux does not use C or D so you will need to clearly understand linux partitioning terminology before proceeding. Linux uses /dev/sdxy - See - http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/partitioning or similar as well as http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: Use virtual machine. That way you don't need to deal with partitions and won't mess up the hard drive if you click something wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu Keeping Data in Different Partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543927/replace-windows-8-1-with-ubuntu-keeping-data-in-different-partition)

Answer (score -1):

You may consider:

1. Use a virtual machine (VM). Options are: VMware Workstation Player (https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0), and VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Upon installation of one of those virtual machine software, you should be able to create a virtual machine, then create its virtual hard drive as a file on your C drive. If you are not satisfied with your virtual machine and want to delete it, you can safely delete the virtual machine's home folder on your physical hard drive.
2. **For Windows 7 or lower**, use "wubi" (See this for details: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide). This tool comes with an official Ubuntu installation image. You can run "wubi" in your Windows from the image. It creates a virtual hard drive which you can choose its location and size. It also adds an Ubuntu item into your Windows boot manager.
3. If you want to install an independent installation of Ubuntu - **not recommended if you are new to Linux**, you CANNOT install it in any existing Windows partitions (C:, D:, or whatever visible in Windows) because Linux and Windows should use different file systems by default to ensure normal operation (ext4 and NTFS respectively). In this way you have to shrink one of your current partitions, and create an ext4 partition for Ubuntu (probably a Linux swap partition too).

Comment: This answer is all wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 Explain.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think VM and "wubi" does solve his problem, why is it all wrong?

Comment: VM is not a good option at all. wibi is a really bad option. It is not supported and does not work with new Windows versions.

Comment: @Pilot6 VM may not be a good option for you but it is safe for a new user who **wants to install Ubuntu on C**.  The poster didn't say what version of Windows he is using and I provided wubi's details so he can refer to it. None of my suggestion is wrong. Again, they may not be the best solution for you but it can be safer for new users.

Comment: @Pilot6 It is irresponsible of you just to comment a "this answer is all wrong" without explanation, by the way.